# SQLBase error HY092

Tags: odbc, sqlbase

I'm trying to config a connection with SQLBase with odbc driver on Windows and I never did that, but I'm getting the error:

```
Connection failed with SQL State: "HY092"
```

I'm using the Windows ODBC Administrator to try add the connection. In the field "Config Filename (INI)" of the configuration screen I put: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Centura\sql.ini"` and I add `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Centura\"` to the PATH system variable.

In the application (.NET) I'm getting the message:

```
ERROR [HY092] [Gupta][ODBC Driver]Invalid attribute/option identifier
```

My sql.ini file has the content:

```
[win32client]
clientname=CWBXXX

[win32client.dll]
comdll=sqlws32

[win32client.
serverpath=server3,<SERVER_IP>,2155/<BASE_NAME>
```

Anyone could help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you are using SQLBase . Awesome.
Two important settings to get right.

1) Make sure you are using the **correct** ODBC administrator 
I'm guessing 32 bit in %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe. 
If not , use the 64bit one in  %systemdrive%\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe. 
Under **System DSN** tab Add the correct driver for the database. Either **'Centura SQLBase 3.6 32bit Driver'** or the **'Gupta SQLBase 12.x'** driver if you are running SQLBase 12.
Under the **Configure Tab**, specify the Data Source Name that you will use in your sql.ini.  THEY MUST MATCH.

2)a. Make sure you only ever have 1 sql.ini on the client. Ever.
2)b. sql.ini needs the ODBC driver specified in the client section:

```
[win32client.dll]
comdll=sqlodb32

 [odbcrtr]
 odbctrace=off
 longbuffer=32767
 buffrow=10000

 remotedbname=[dB Name specified in ODBC] , 
 DSN=[Data Source Name specified in ODBC]
```

(without the square brackets eg. remotedbname=MyDatabase,DSN=MyDatasetName whatever names you have specified in ODBC admin.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a SQLBase old version, for some reason Gupta SQLBase driver don't work so I tried to install the Centura SQLBase 32bit driver and works fine.

Comment: If you get the opportunity - consider an upgrade to SQLBase v12.2. You'll be blown away by performance boost and extra features. And its so easy to upgrade. Note that I'm NOT affiliated or related to OpenText,Gupta, Centura or any of their products in any way - I just really like the Database and toolset.